# Como passar dados do Angular para uma classe em php?

Tags: php, angularjs

Tenho o seguinte código em Angular:

```
 <script>
 angular.module("fluxo", ["ngRoute"]);

.factory('factCliente', ['$http', function($http) {
    var _getData2 = function(id_empresa) {
    return $http.post("php/index.php", id_empresa);
};

return {
    getData2: _getData2
}
}])

.controller("fluxoCtrl", function ($scope, $http, factCliente) {

    var id_empresa = {id_empresa: 1};
    factCliente.getData2(id_empresa).then(function(response) {
        $scope.mostraTodasContasEntradas = response;
    }, function(error) {
        console.log("Ocorreu um erro: " + error);
    });
});
</script>
```

E o meu código em php que inclui a classe e chama a devida função que quero chamar

```
<?php
 require_once "../con/conexao.php";
 require_once "../classes/contaEntrada.php";

 $entrada = new contaEntrada();

 $payload = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
 $id_empresa = $payload->id_empresa;

 $id_empresa = $_POST['id_empresa'];

 $entrada->mostraContasEntrada($id_empresa);
?>
```

Sei que o erro está aqui, nesse código em php, mas não sei onde.
Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: onde está o $_POST?

Comment: Desculpe, eu já tinha ajustado de $_GET pra $_POST, mas não tinha atualizado @MarceloBonus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Os posts no angular são disparados como Request Payload, então no lado do PHP você pode recebe-los dessa maneira

```
$payload = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
$id_empresa = $payload->id_empresa;
```

Remova também o `;` da linha 2 do script
e no seu controller defina a variável id empresa da seguinte maneira

```
var id_empresa = {id_empresa: 1};
```

código completo funcionando:

Script:

```
<script>
 angular.module("fluxo", ["ngRoute"])

.factory('factCliente', ['$http', function($http) {
    var _getData2 = function(id_empresa) {
    return $http.post("php/index.php", id_empresa);
};

return {
    getData2: _getData2
}
}])

.controller("fluxoCtrl", function ($scope, $http, factCliente) {

    var id_empresa = {id_empresa: 1};
    factCliente.getData2(id_empresa).then(function(response) {
        $scope.mostraTodasContasEntradas = response;
    }, function(error) {
        console.log("Ocorreu um erro: " + error);
    });
});
</script>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
 require_once "../con/conexao.php";
 require_once "../classes/contaEntrada.php";

 $entrada = new contaEntrada();

 $payload = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
 $id_empresa = $payload->id_empresa;

 $entrada->mostraContasEntrada($id_empresa);
?>
```

Comment: Mudei mas agora estou recebendo essa mensagem no console:

"Undefined index: id_empresa in <b>/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/sistemas/sistemas_web/fluxo_de_caixa/fluxojoin_v_hap/php/index.php</b> on line <b>15"

Comment: Você consegue checar no console se a variável id_empresa está realmente sendo *postada*

Comment: @GustavoSevero editei minha resposta, da uma olhada agora.

Comment: Alan, ajustei meu código, como você sugeriu e a mensagem continua.

"Undefined index: id_empresa in <b>/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/sistemas/sistemas_web/fluxo_de_caixa/fluxojoin_v_hap/php/index.php</b> on line <b>15</b><br /><b>Warning</b>: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/sistemas/sistemas_web/fluxo_de_caixa/fluxojoin_v_hap/php/index.php:15) in <b>/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/sistemas/sistemas_web/fluxo_de_caixa/fluxojoin_v_hap/classes/contaEntrada.php</b> on line <b>52</b><br />"

Comment: Can you show the updated files?

Comment: Eu tentei remover a seguinte linha do arquivo php:

$id_empresa = $_POST['id_empresa'];

E a mensagem que apareceu no console foi:

"SyntaxError: Unexpected token <"

E apontava para o arquivo do angular.js

Comment: Como.......????

Comment: Opa me empolguei no ingles, retire o $_POST do seu index

Comment: A linha toda, você quer dizer?

Comment: Sim a linha , você removeu o ; do final da linha 2 do seu js?

Comment: Sim removi... O meu código atual, está aqui no post, atualizei...
Qual linha do js é pra retirar, exatamente?

Comment: retire o `;` que fica no final da linha `angular.module("fluxo", ["ngRoute"]);`

Comment: e retire a linha `$id_empresa = $_POST['id_empresa'];` do seu index.php

Comment: Pronto, ajustei... E continua a mesma mensagem.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31540/discussion-between-alan-rezende-and-gustavosevero).